# How to check multidimensional array only contain int value in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to check multidimensional array only contain int value in php

Is there any Easiest to check this.

Like i have an array that contain int value but i have to check that all value are in or not

**Array 1**

```
$RoomGuests = array(
                        array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> 2,
                         "NoOfChild"=>0,
                        ),
                        array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
                         "NoOfChild"=>2,
                         "ChildAge"=> array(12,11)
                        ),
                        array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
                         "NoOfChild"=>1,
                         "ChildAge"=> array(11)
                        )
                    );
```

Above array only contained int value then it is **true**

**Array2**

```
$RoomGuests2 = array(
                        array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> "two",
                         "NoOfChild"=>0,
                        ),
                        array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> "three",
                         "NoOfChild"=>"two",
                         "ChildAge"=> array(12,11)
                        ),
                        array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
                         "NoOfChild"=>1,
                         "ChildAge"=> array(11)
                        )
                    );
```

Above array not contained int value then it is **false**

**Array3**

```
$RoomGuests3 = array(
                    array(
                     "NoOfAdults"=> 2,
                     "NoOfChild"=>0,
                    ),
                    array(
                     "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
                     "NoOfChild"=>2,
                     "ChildAge"=> array(12,11)
                    ),
                    array(
                     "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
                     "NoOfChild"=>1,
                     "ChildAge"=> array(
                         "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
                         "NoOfChild"=>1,
                         "ChildAge"=> array(11,'k')
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help you

```
var_dump(is_IntArray($RoomGuests));
var_dump(is_IntArray($RoomGuests2));
var_dump(is_IntArray($RoomGuests3));

function is_IntArray($p){
    $Result = is_array($p) ?
            implode('', array_map(__FUNCTION__, array_fill(0, count($p), ''), $p)) : 
            $p;
    return ctype_digit($Result);
}
```

Comment: Bingo this work in all condition Thanks @AjayDeepakKumar

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `foreach()` to loop the father array and the `array_walk_recursive()` function to check the children.

Like this:

```
$RoomGuests2 = array(
      array(
       "NoOfAdults"=> "two",
       "NoOfChild"=>0,
      ),
      array(
       "NoOfAdults"=> "three",
       "NoOfChild"=>"two",
       "ChildAge"=> array(12,11)
      ),
      array(
       "NoOfAdults"=> 3,
       "NoOfChild"=>1,
       "ChildAge"=> array(11)
      )
);

foreach($RoomGuest2 as $child) {
      array_walk_recursive($child, 'checkIfInt');
}

function checkIfInt($array, $key) {
      // If the child array is another array (like "ChildAge"=> array(11)) then check this array.
      if(is_array($array[$key])) array_walk_recursive($array[$key], 'checkIfInt');
      else if(!is_integer($array[$key])) {
            // If the value it's not a integer, then PHP will execute this code. 
      }
}
```

Comment: This is terrible nit-picking on my part. An anonymous function can be passed as a closure to `array_walk_recursive` if you want to make the code shorter, however it will have access only to local scope if no `use` is specified.  Arguably it may be better or worst, depending on what OP wants to do with the code. Also you don't really need the `foreach` since it will walk the whole array, no matter the dept.

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean that the code could be like this:


`array_walk_recursive($child, function() {});`


If yes, I put the code in another function to make the code easier to understand.

Comment: @Syncro Yes. That's exactly what I mean, but I see your point about easier to read code.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew
User97798 just edit my code and make it work with your array, it's very simple.

Comment: Show me the code @User97798 (with your edits obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
function containsOnlyIntegers($array) {
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        foreach($arr as $k => $a) {
            if ($k === 'NoOfAdults' || $k === 'NoOfChild') {
                if (!is_int($a)) { return false; }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```